# How do I make Ubuntu 20.04 work on Windows 10 WSL 2?

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have followed the instructions of [Microsoft] (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and [this] (https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/how-to-install-wsl2-on-windows-10) verbatim. However, all I got is this error message which I cannot find further info. What did I miss?
[image: Error Message]

Comment: 80370102 is a WINDOWS error. Use the windows knowledge base to search that error and it will likely state you forgot to enable virtualization in the BIOS of your system.  Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264102/wsl-2-wont-run-ubuntu-error-0x80370102

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks. However, my problem persisted after I followed what they did in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I got everything working after:

1. using System Restore to recover the point immediately after the **Win10 2004 update** (that's actually the earliest restore point for my system)—be patient as it can take a while (also the first restart of the whole process)
2. enabling virtualization in BIOS (for my HP, it's under the tab **Security->System Security->Virtual Technology->Enable**)—the second restart
3. after Windows 10 restarted, navigating the Start Menu: Windows Settings->Apps->Optional features->More Windows features->**Turn Windows features on or off** to select both *Virtual Machine Platform* and *Windows Subsystem for Linux* (I didn't choose *Windows Hypervisor Platform* in the list)—the third restart ensued
4. after restarting, visit *Microsoft Store* from the Windows Start Menu and install *Ubuntu*
5. installing [the Linux kernel update package](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi) (https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi)
6. starting an **elevated** PowerShell session to run

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

7. Launching *Ubuntu* after the installation is complete. Create a new user account with password.

What I have now is Ubuntu 20.04 running nicely on Win 10 WSL2.
[image: Screenshot]