# WSL2 Ubuntu won't launch on Windows 11 Home

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As mentioned in the GitHub issue I went to Windows Security but both vmvp.exe and vmcompute.exe didn't have any overrides, also there is no override called Code Flow Guard, but two overrides called Code Integrity Guard and Control Flow Guard ( I suspect this is due to Windows 11 ).

[image: overrides for vmcompute][image: CFG unchecked]

I still get this error so if anyone could clarify it would be greatly appreciated
[image: ubuntu wsl2 error]

Other Info:

- OS: Windows 11 Home
- AMD CPU

Output of `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object { $_.State -eq "Enabled" } | Select-Object FeatureName | clip`

```
FeatureName                                
-----------                                
Windows-Defender-Default-Definitions       
Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features       
Printing-XPSServices-Features              
SearchEngine-Client-Package                
WorkFolders-Client                         
Printing-Foundation-Features               
Printing-Foundation-InternetPrinting-Client
MSRDC-Infrastructure                       
MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root           
MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2               
NetFx4-AdvSrvs                             
WCF-Services45                             
WCF-TCP-PortSharing45                      
SMB1Protocol                               
SMB1Protocol-Client                        
SMB1Protocol-Deprecation                   
MediaPlayback                              
WindowsMediaPlayer                         
Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Related Links:

- [WSL 2 Won't Run Ubuntu - Error 0x80370102](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264102/wsl-2-wont-run-ubuntu-error-0x80370102)
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5964

Comment: A Windows problem not Ubuntu.

Comment: @David WSL questions regarding Ubuntu are on-topic here. It may be a Windows problem, but it is preventing the use of an official Canonical release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jytesh It's going to be very rare that the issue is due to some security settings in Windows unless you've customized those security settings in the first place.  Far more likely that it's something more basic.  Try running PowerShell as Administrator and run `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object { $_.State -eq "Enabled" } | Select-Object FeatureName | clip`.  Then paste the results into your question.  Thanks!

Comment: WSL2 Ubuntu won't launch is an Ubuntu problem too, therefore this question is on topic at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This is something analogous to "Ubuntu does not launch due to a hardware issue". Sure, it is related to an official Canonical release, but it is an Windows issue, and is not very on topic on this site, just like hardware issues.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi While WSL questions may often be *better* suited for another site like Super User, we don't and can't expect the user to know whether their problem is something that is going to require Windows or Ubuntu expertise (or both!) in advance.  Also, please see [this Meta answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17935/1165986) from Zanna (mod) -- *"WSL is Ubuntu and questions about running it are on topic.  We should not close questions just because they smell ... Windowsy."*  Also the referenced [Is WSL on-topic](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15229/1165986) meta question and answer.

Comment: I never said this is OFF TOPIC. The error messages are MICROSOFT error messages. MICROSOFT error messages can only be looked up on a MICROSOFT site. Please do not put words in my mouth. Nor did I suggest closing the question.

Comment: I am sorry if this is off topic, where in stack exchange should I take up this question? Super User or answers.microsoft.com? 

I Have also added the output of command @NotTheDr01ds

Comment: @Jytesh Right here is just fine. I think I see the problem based on the output you provided, but I'm on mobile at the moment, so it will be a bit before I can check my system to make sure.

Comment: @David Not sure what comment you are replying to - It may have been deleted since I don't see anyone saying that you said it was off-topic or that you said it should be closed.  That said, it's kind of hard to read your first comment here as anything but "go away."  And I would disagree that you have to go to a Microsoft site for help with this.  There are those of us who are happy to support this question here.

Comment: @Jytesh "VirtualMachinePlatform" is missing from your list.  This is the main component that is needed for WSL2.  Can you try `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart` (also from an Administrator PowerShell)?  I'm guessing you are going to get an error there, but knowing what it is might get us one step closer.  If it does work, then restart Windows and try the Ubuntu install again.  Thanks!

Comment: Enabled it ( Checked with same command ), but it still shows `Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370114
Error: 0x80370114 The operation could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

Press any key to continue...`

After 40 minutes of installing

Comment: I got it working after installing Hypver-V and enabling VirtualMachinePlatform thanks @NotTheDr01ds :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user @NotTheDr01ds noted, VirtualMachinePlatform was disabled, but even after enabling it the issue persisted, I needed to enable Hyper-V to make it work, Hyper-V is not installed in Windows Home versions so I followed this tutorial to  install it, after that I disabled WSL , restarted enabled it and restarted again to make it work.

Hyper-V in Home installation : https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/download-and-install-hyper-v-on-windows-10-home.html